# Why $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2k}e^{-ax^2} \mbox{d}x = \frac{1\cdot 3\cdots (2k-1)}{2^k}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^{2k+1}}}\quad ?$

Tags: calculus

Given the identity $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} \mbox{d}x = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}},\tag{1}$$ why differentiating $(1)$ $k$ times gives

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2k}e^{-ax^2} \mbox{d}x = \frac{1\cdot 3\cdots (2k-1)}{2^k}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^{2k+1}}} \tag{2}\quad ?$$ Could you please someone give some guidelines or a proof?

Comment: What does "guidelines" mean: are you asking for a proof, or to see an example?  It is based on differentiation under the integral sign, used repeatedly. See Section 5 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the link I start form there. Of course a stand alone proof is also very welcome.

Comment: @KCd I do not understand this part: When $n$ is odd, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n e^{-x^2/2} \mbox{d}x$ vanishes since $x^n e^{-x^2/2}$ is an odd function. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: An odd function always has integral $0$ on intervals of the form $[-a,a]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) with
\begin{align}
u(x)&=x^{2k-1}
\\
u'(x) &= (2k-1) x^{2k-2}
\\
v'(x) &= x e^{-ax^2}
\\
v(x) &= -\frac{1}{2a}e^{-ax^2}
\end{align}
yields
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2k} e^{-ax^2} \, dx
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x) v'(x) \, dx
\\
&= [u(x) v(x)]_{x=-\infty}^\infty - \int v(x) u'(x) \, dx
\\
&= \underbrace{\left[-\frac{1}{2a}x^{2k-1} e^{-ax^2}\right]_{x=-\infty}^\infty}_{=0}
+ \frac{2k-1}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^\infty  x^{2k-2} e^{-ax^2} \, dx.
\end{align}

Repeating this process until you arrive at the base case $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2} \, dx$ yields the desired expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could  you please elaborate a little more on how $u$ and $v$ are used? Some more lines are highly appreciated.

Comment: @darkmoor Added more details about integration by parts.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I did the rest of the computations for exercise:

$$\begin{aligned}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2k} e^{-a x^2}\mbox{d}x = \frac{2k-1}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2k-2\cdot1} e^{-a x^2}\mbox{d}x  = \frac{2k-1}{2a} \frac{2k-3}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2k-2\cdot 2} e^{-a x^2}\mbox{d}x = \dots = \frac{2k-1}{2a} \frac{2k-3}{2a}\cdots \frac{2k-(2k-1)}{2a} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^{2k-2\cdot k} e^{-a x^2}\mbox{d}x = \frac{1\cdot 3\cdots (2k-1)}{2^k}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a^{2k+1}}}\end{aligned}$$.

Comment: Please let me ask something else. Thanks to @KCd's comment, in an alternative proof using [_differentiation under the integral sign_](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf), I see that there are two cases. One for $k$ odd and one for $k$ even. I think that your proof is for the case where $k$ is even but I can not see how both cases are related with your approach. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @darkmoor The case when $n$ is odd is handled in one sentence, both in the PDF and by KCd's comment. When $n$ is even, the PDF uses differentiation to go from $n=0$ to $n=2$ to $n=4$ and so on. Integration by parts goes backwards for even $n$ down to $0$.